# In Trello, how can I show the card numbers?

Tags: jquery, bookmarklet, bookmarks, trello

Short numbers are very useful handles for working with cards (in discussions, tracking, etc).  Trello has numbers associated with cards, but they don't show them for some reason.  How can I display card numbers in Trello?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out card numbers are actually in Trello's HTML but hidden with no setting I can find to show them.  There are extensions to do this, but I don't want to give an extension access to my stuff just to do a simple thing like this.  So I did it with jQuery:

```
javascript:(function(){
    $('span.card-short-id').removeClass('hide');
    $('span.card-short-id').css('padding-right','5px');
    $('span.card-short-id').css('font-weight','bold');
    $('span.card-short-id').css('font-size','16px');
})()
```

Paste that into a browser bookmark's URL field.

Here is the same without the whitespace if needed (Chrome handles the whitespace fine though):

```
javascript:(function(){$('span.card-short-id').removeClass('hide');    $('span.card-short-id').css('padding-right','5px');$('span.card-short-id').css('font-weight','bold');$('span.card-short-id').css('font-size','16px');})()
```

Comment: Note: I now use an extension that works great called "Trello Card Numbers" by John DeWyze: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-card-numbers/kadpkdielickimifpinkknemjdipghaf

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the solution here. Its free and works like a charm:
https://youtu.be/BEwRtcOXkPg

Comment: yep, I mentioned that a couple or so years ago in my comment, with an actual link to the extension :)